# Acme cookbook not working as expected

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, lets-encrypt

I'm creating a cookbook that creates a self signed cert for nginx and hopefully uses the certbot cookbook to overwrite the self-signed cert for a letsencrypt cert:

```
# Create self signed certificate
acme_selfsigned 'timber.com' do
  crt     '/etc/letsencrypt/live/timber.com/cert.pem'
  chain   '/etc/letsencrypt/live/timber.com/chain.pem'
  key     '/etc/letsencrypt/live/timber.com/privkey.pem'
end

# Create letsencrypt cert
certbot_certonly_webroot 'timber.com' do
  webroot_path '/home_page/'
  email 'lumber@timber.com'
  domains ['timber.com']
  retries           5
  retry_delay       240
  notifies :restart, resources(:service => "nginx")
  agree_tos true
end
```

The nginx self signed site comes up correctly but cerbot does not overwrite the existing self-signed cert in:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/timber.com/
```

Instead it makes a second cert at:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/timber.com-0001/
```

Does anyone know of a way to replace / overwrite the original cert?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two Chef cookbooks. acme cookbook [can handle your use case](https://github.com/schubergphilis/chef-acme#example). It will replace self-signed easily and it will restart nginx afterwards.

Comment: I switched to the cerbot cookbook for the cert generation part as the acme_certificate resource was failing to create a cert while the certbot resource works to create a cert. I could use anything to create the self signed cert but just kept the acme cookbook in place since that part was working.

Comment: Maybe would it be better to fix acme_certificate? Why it was failing?